# Use workspace of an RStudio session in Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter

As my RAM is scarce, I'd like to not replicate data and use objects created in an RStudio session inside my Jupyter notebook (running w/ R kernel).

Any idea how to do it?
Basically I'd like to use the same workspace in both, the RStudio and the Jupyter notebook session.

Thanks for help!

Comment: pick one tech and use it or PR into either project to enable the sharing. they both use completely different session "servers" and use different methods to create and access each session.

Comment: You can consider to use RStudio Notebooks: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html

Answer (score 2):

One problem I encountered with an R notebook in Jupyter, though, was saving my workspace. In a normal R session I’m used to saving my workspace at the end of the session and coming back to it later to pick up where I left off. However, with the Jupyter notebook I found that I had to rerun all the code to regenerate all the objects again! This appears to be an issue for Python notebook users too.

There’s a very simple fix for this: Just run the standard R command
save.image()

Your workspace will then be saved to the usual hidden .RData file in the same folder as the Jupyter notebook. If you want to share the code and the workspace, you’ll have to make sure that you copy both the notebook file and the .RData file that goes along with it.

Likewise, if you start a notebook in a folder that already has an .RData file, you’ll find that you can access that workspace from the Jupyter notebook – just run ls() to see what’s there.